Unconfirmed transaction what to do
What does "this outpost has been spend" means? I made a transaction from my wallet to other wallet. Its been 3 days. Both wallets have "unconfirmed balance" with same amount.
When i check transaction chain my wallet +2 others have a red cross.
Is my coins still existing or they vanished?
A total noob at this btw. Also a woman. Well, u get the picture :P

This question is similar to: Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
